# POST http://localhost:3000/post/vote 500 (Internal Server Error) - No route matches [GET] "/post/vote" when trying to post ajax in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am working with the voting button and try to post the ajax in RoR but cannot get through it.

Kindly check my route controller and the ajax as follows:

```
  post 'post/vote' => 'votes#create'
```

```
class VotesController < ApplicationController
  def create
    vote = Vote.new
    post_id = params[:post_id]
    vote.post_id = params[:post_id]
    vote.account_id = current_account.id
    existing_vote = Vote.where(account_id: current_account.id, post_id: post_id)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js do
        if existing_vote.size > 0
          existing_vote.first.destroy
        else
          @success = if vote.save
                       true
                     else
                       false
                     end

          @post = Post.find(post_id)
          @total_upvotes = @post.upvotes
          @total_downvotes = @post.downvotes
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

```
$(function () {
  $(".vote").on("click", ".upvote", function () {
    let post_id = $(this).parent().data("id");
    console.log("clicked " + post_id);

    $.ajax({
      url: "post/vote",
      type:'POST',
      data: { post_id: post_id },
      success: function(){
        console.log("success");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass):
  
app/controllers/votes_controller.rb:6:in `create'
Started POST "/post/vote" for ::1 at 2021-02-27 12:58:29 +0700
Processing by VotesController#create as */*
  Parameters: {"post_id"=>"2"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 3ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 1234)


  
NoMethodError (undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass):
  
app/controllers/votes_controller.rb:6:in `create'
```

What I want at this point is to log the "success" why the error POST http://localhost:3000/post/vote 500 (Internal Server Error) appears and when I try to go to the http://localhost:3000/post/vote it shows No route matches [GET] "/post/vote" when trying to post ajax.

Comment: Can you share the rails logs for the POST request?

Comment: Yes sir it was as below: 

NoMethodError (undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass):
  
app/controllers/votes_controller.rb:6:in `create'
Started POST "/post/vote" for ::1 at 2021-02-27 12:58:29 +0700
Processing by VotesController#create as */*
  Parameters: {"post_id"=>"2"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 3ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 1234)


  
NoMethodError (undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass):
  
app/controllers/votes_controller.rb:6:in `create'

Comment: omg really sorry for my foolishness and thank you for your help! Sorry I thought it is going to work but the new problem comes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `current_account` is `nil`. Add the following code to `VotesController` to make sure the user is authenticated.

```rb
before_action :authenticate_account!
```

The `authenticate_account!` method will get called for every action defined in the controller.

Comment: now the  POST http://localhost:3000/post/vote 401 (Unauthorized) appears instead with ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/post/vote"):

Comment: @Kamidesu Is the user logged in? And why is a GET request sent to `/post/vote`?

Comment: Sorry sir I forgot to login before tryin the button but still have no idea why there was the GET request when I did not login. Anyways, than you for your help.

Comment: The `VotesController#create` method renders `votes/create.js.erb` right? Why are you using `$.ajax` then? You can use `button_to` with `remote: true` for the upvote button.

Comment: Appreciate your suggesstion. This is a part of my learning and I just tried to follow a tutorial. It says something like there are many posts and upvote-downvote buttons so better to use js than the form but it didnt tell me the reason.